# jQuery Knob doesn't trigger at event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to trigger an event like release or change event with a jQuery knob. According to [documentation](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob#hooks), it should work with this:

```
<script>
    $(".dial").knob({
        'release' : function (v) { /*make something*/ }
    });
</script>
```

In my code i have something very similar:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <title>Knobs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/text.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="knobBar">
      <input id="gain1" class="knob"
        data-angleOffset=-125
        data-angleArc=250
        data-bgColor="#262626"
        data-fgColor="#00ff00"
        data-rotation="clockwise"
        value="0"
        data-min="0"
        data-max="100"
        data-lineCap="round"
        data-displayPrevious="true"
        data-width="5%"
        data-font="Advanced LED Board-7">
</body>
```

And I put this at the end of the html file:

```
<script>
//Listeners for Knobs changes
$(function () {
  $('#gain1').knob({
      'release': function (v) {
    console.log(v);
    gain_1.gain.value = v / 100;
  }});
  }) 
</script>
```

I just don't get it to work. It doesn't print anything to console, so obviously is not triggering the function.

Comment: Try closing your input and div tags? Works for me though: http://plnkr.co/edit/n4XpntOiJsPtl9D6uzix?p=preview

Comment: I think you're missing `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Resolved. The problem was at the declaration in <script> tag in the html file. The jQuery must be declarated first than any other javascript file.